# Checking if an NSString contains base64 data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, base64, nsdata

How can I check to see if an NSString contains base64 data in an if statement? Because base64 encodes the data in a completely random way, I can't search for a phrase within the NSString so instead I will need to check to see if the contents of the string results in a data file.

Comment: to check if a string is base64 encoded http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571501/how-to-check-whether-the-string-is-base64-encoded-or-not reads promising.

Comment: You can't check, with 100% reliability.  All you can do is see if it MIGHT be base64.  (And it's a poor design where you would not know from some other source whether the data is base64 or not.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a category on `NSString` I created that should work:

```
@interface NSString (MDBase64Additions)
- (BOOL)isBase64Data;
@end

@implementation NSString (MDBase64Additions)

- (BOOL)isBase64Data {
    if ([self length] % 4 == 0) {
        static NSCharacterSet *invertedBase64CharacterSet = nil;
        if (invertedBase64CharacterSet == nil) {
            invertedBase64CharacterSet = [[[NSCharacterSet
               characterSetWithCharactersInString:
        @"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/="]
                                     invertedSet] retain];
        }
        return [self rangeOfCharacterFromSet:invertedBase64CharacterSet
           options:NSLiteralSearch].location == NSNotFound;
    }
    return NO;
}

@end
```

If you expect newlines or blank spaces in the data, you could update this method to remove those first (likely `NSCharacterSet`'s `+whitespaceCharacterSet`).

If there's primarily just one class where you'll be using this category method, you could put this code inside its .m file above that class's `@implementation` block. If you think you might want to use that category from more than one class, you could create a separate .h & .m pair to contain it (e.g. `MDFoundationAdditions.h`, `MDFoundationAdditions.m`), and then import it into those classes.

To use:

```
NSString *dataString = /* assume exists */;

if ([dataString isBase64Data]) {

}
```

Comment: thanks for this. Would I create a .m file with the first bit of code in then import it?

Comment: This is not working for me,  BOOL result1 = [self isBase64Data:@"Rayan"];
    BOOL result2 = [self isBase64Data:@"Khan"]; for result 1 it returns NO and for result2 it return YES.