# Check if a string is encoded in base64 using Python

Tags: python, base64

Is there a good way to check if a string is encoded in `base64` using Python?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This isn't possible. The best you could do would be to verify that a string might be valid Base 64, although many strings consisting of only ASCII text can be decoded as if they were Base 64.

Comment: Is this really the answer?

Comment: @coler-j yes, it is technically correct. It also probably should have been a comment but in 2012 SO was different. Maybe.

Answer (score 79):

I was looking for a solution to the same problem, then a very simple one just struck me in the head. All you need to do is decode, then re-encode. If the re-encoded string is equal to the encoded string, then it is base64 encoded.
Here is the code:

```
import base64

def isBase64(s):
    try:
        return base64.b64encode(base64.b64decode(s)) == s
    except Exception:
        return False
```

That's it!

Edit: Here's a version of the function that works with both the string and bytes objects in Python 3:

```
import base64

def isBase64(sb):
        try:
                if isinstance(sb, str):
                        # If there's any unicode here, an exception will be thrown and the function will return false
                        sb_bytes = bytes(sb, 'ascii')
                elif isinstance(sb, bytes):
                        sb_bytes = sb
                else:
                        raise ValueError("Argument must be string or bytes")
                return base64.b64encode(base64.b64decode(sb_bytes)) == sb_bytes
        except Exception:
                return False
```

Comment: Nice and simple, I like it!

Comment: If you like lambda: `isBase64 = lambda x: x.decode('base64').encode('base64').replace('\n','') == x` Note that this code will sometimes throw an incorrect padding exception.

Comment: Side note: you can always just `return base64.b64encode(base64.b64decode(s)) == s` instead of using an if statement and returning a constant bool result :)

Comment: True, but then you'll have to handle the binascii exceptions yourself outside the function as well.

Comment: `isBase64('test')` return True

Comment: @ahmed that's because "test" is a valid base64 string. Base64 includes a-z, A-Z, 0-9, +, /, and = for padding.

Comment: Ah, d0nut, I think I get what you mean. Editing.

Comment: on Python3 since `str` and `bytes` comparison doesn't covert them to same type implicitly(for the comparison) I had to do `return base64.b64encode(base64.b64decode(s)).decode() == s` for this to work. As my `s` was a unicode `str` while the value returned from `base64.b64encode(base64.b64decode(s))` was `bytes`. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30580386/1781024

Comment: Vikas Prasad, thanks! I just added a version of the function for Python 3 that works on both `str` and `bytes`.

Comment: You actually need `base64.b64decode(sb_bytes, validate=True)`, otherwise it considers quoted-printable transport encoding as valid base64

Answer (score 39):

```
import base64
import binascii

try:
    base64.decodestring("foo")
except binascii.Error:
    print "no correct base64"
```

Comment: thank you, but I was wondering if it exists a function to test this instead of putting a try

Comment: I don't find any in [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/base64.html?highlight=base64#base64).

Comment: "easier to ask for forgiveness than permission", although I'd probably favour catching the actual exception that's likely to be raised (which I think will be binascii.Error)

Comment: This is incorrect, `base64.decodestring('čččč')` returns an empty string and no exception but I dont't think the string čččč is valid base64

Comment: base64.decodestring("dfdsfsdf ds fk") doesn't raise TypeError neither, the string doesn't seem to be a base64 string

Comment: As of 2018, Python 3.7, I use `base64.b64decode(item)` instead, and it works.

Comment: base64.decodestring("dfdsfsdf ds fk") is actually a base64 string. The base64 method ignores whitespace and what you are left with is a valid base64 string.

Comment: `base64.b64decode(s, validate=true)` will decode `s` if it is valid, and otherwise throw an exception. `base64.decodestring` is very permissive and will strip any non-base64 characters which is potentially problematic.

Answer (score 12):

The solution I used is based on one of the prior answers, but uses more up to date calls.

In my code, the my_image_string is either the image data itself in raw form or it's a base64 string.  If the decode fails, then I assume it's raw data.

Note the `validate=True` keyword argument to  `b64decode`.  This is required in order for the assert to be generated by the decoder.  Without it there will be no complaints about an illegal string.

```
import base64, binascii

try:
    image_data = base64.b64decode(my_image_string, validate=True)
except binascii.Error:
    image_data = my_image_string
```

Answer (score 6):

Using Python RegEx

```
import re

txt = "VGhpcyBpcyBlbmNvZGVkIHRleHQ="
x = re.search("^([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)?$", txt)

if (x):
  print("Encoded")
else:
  print("Non encoded")
```

Answer (score 3):

Before trying to decode, I like to do a formatting check first as its the lightest weight check and does not return false positives thus following [fail-fast](https://dzone.com/articles/fail-fast-principle-in-software-development) coding principles.

Here is a utility function for this task:

```
RE_BASE64 = "^([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)?$"
def likeBase64(s:str) -> bool:
    return False if s is None or not re.search(RE_BASE64, s) else True
```

Answer (score 2):

if the length of the encoded string is the times of 4, it can be decoded

```
base64.encodestring("whatever you say").strip().__len__() % 4 == 0
```

so, you just need to check if the string can match something like above, then it won't throw any exception(I Guess =.=)

```
if len(the_base64string.strip()) % 4 == 0:
    # then you can just decode it anyway
    base64.decodestring(the_base64string)
```

Comment: This does not work for strings with \n in them that are still valid base64

Answer (score 2):

@geoffspear is correct in that this is not 100% possible but you can get pretty close by checking the string header to see if it matches that of a base64 encoded string (re: [How to check whether a string is base64 encoded or not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8571649)).

```
# check if a string is base64 encoded.
def isBase64Encoded(s):
    pattern = re.compile("^([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)$")
    if not s or len(s) < 1:
        return False
    else:
        return pattern.match(s)
```

Also not that in my case I wanted to return false if the string is empty to avoid decoding as there's no use in decoding nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm almost 8 years late but you can use a regex expression thus you can verify if a given input is BASE64.

```
import re

encoding_type = 'Encoding type: '
base64_encoding = 'Base64'


def is_base64():
    element = input("Enter encoded element: ")
    expression = "^([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)?$"

    matches = re.match(expression, element)

    if matches:
        print(f"{encoding_type + base64_encoding}")
    else:
        print("Unknown encoding type.")


is_base64()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_base64(s):
    s = ''.join([s.strip() for s in s.split("\n")])
    try:
        enc = base64.b64encode(base64.b64decode(s)).strip()
        return enc == s
    except TypeError:
        return False
```

In my case, my input, `s`, had newlines which I had to strip before the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 'possibly base64 encoded string'
result = x
try:
   decoded = x.decode('base64', 'strict')
   if x == decoded.encode('base64').strip():
       result = decoded
except:
   pass
```

this code put in the result variable decoded string if x is really encoded, and just x if not. Just try to decode doesn't always work.

Comment: instead of   x == decoded.encode('base64').strip() should be x == decoded.encode('base64').replace('\n', '')   because of in some cases encode add several '\n'