# Why does comparison of bytes with str fails in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

In Python 3 this expression evaluates as `False`:

```
b"" == ""
```

While in Python 2 this comparison is `True`:

```
u"" == ""
```

Checking for identity with `is` obviously fails in both cases.

But why would they implement such a behaviour in Python 3?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Python 2.x, the design goal for Unicode is to enable transparent operations between Unicode and byte strings by implicitly converting between the two types.

When you do the comparison `u"" == ""`, the
Unicode [LHS](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/LHS#Noun) is automatically encoded into a byte string first, and then compared to the `str` [RHS](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/RHS#Noun). That's why it returned `True`.

In contrast, Python 3.x, having learned from the mess of Unicode that was in Python 2, decided to make everything about Unicode vs. byte strings explicit. Thus, `b"" == ""` is `False` because the byte string is no longer automatically converted to Unicode for comparison.

Comment: For those who are interested, see [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) :)

Answer (score 29):

In Python 3, strings are Unicode. The type used to hold text is `str` and the type used to hold data is `bytes`.

> the `str` and `bytes` types cannot be mixed, you must always explicitly convert between them. Use `str.encode()` to go from `str` to `bytes`, and `bytes.decode()` to go from bytes to `str`.

Therefore, if you do `b"".decode() == ""`, you'll get `True`:

```
>>> b"".decode() == ""
True
```

For more information, read [*Text Vs. Data Instead Of Unicode Vs. 8-bi*](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit).

Answer (score 5):

The designers decided to not assume an encoding for coercion when comparing bytes to strings, so it falls under the default behavior of Python 3.x whereby comparisons containing differing types fail.