# Unable to encode in b64 : bytes-like object is required not 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, base64, byte

I'm trying to convert a dict to a special query string.

The code is working with python2 but not with 3

For example with this input:

```
{'retry': '0', 'locator': 'gamespy.com', 'datetime': '20201114223555'}
```

I want to get this output:

```
retry=MA**&locator=Z2FtZXNweS5jb20*&datetime=MjAyMDExMTQyMjM1NTU\r\n
```

My dict_to_qs :

```
def dict_to_qs(d):
    ret = {k: base64.b64encode(v).replace("=", "*") for k, v in d.items()}
    return "&".join("{!s}={!s}".format(k, v) for k, v in ret.items()) + "\r\n"
```

but i have this error :

```
  File "/var/www/server/other/utils.py", line 443, in dict_to_qs
        ret = {k: base64.b64encode(v).replace("=", "*") for k, v in d.items()}
      File "/var/www/server/other/utils.py", line 443, in <dictcomp>
        ret = {k: base64.b64encode(v).replace("=", "*") for k, v in d.items()}
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/base64.py", line 58, in b64encode
        encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s, newline=False)
    TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that [`b64encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) requires a bytes-like object and  [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) must be called on a string. [In Python 3 the two types are not implicitly converted like in Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30580865/7259176) and therefore must be converted explicit. You could use the `str.encode()` and `str.decode()` methods.

The below code should be semantically equivalent to your Python 2 example.

```py
def dict_to_qs(d):
    ret = {k: base64.b64encode(str.encode(v)).decode().replace("=", "*") for k, v in d.items()}
    return "&".join("{!s}={!s}".format(k, v) for k, v in ret.items()) + "\r\n"
```

Output: `retry=MA**&locator=Z2FtZXNweS5jb20*&datetime=MjAyMDExMTQyMjM1NTU*\r\n`

Comment: Indeed this is the solution, I had tried to encode it but the variable was not of the right type. Thank you very much, I've just saved a lot of time thanks to your help.