# Detect if Base 64 string is image or text

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, base64, nsdata

Is there a way to detect if the Base 64 string contained in an `NSData` instance is an image or a text or any other object?

Comment: I don't think there's a way. For text you could test if all bytes are characters... but of course, then you have unicode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't generally just look at the base 64 string and decide, but you can decode the first few bytes of data, look at the hex codes (you can do this by decoding your base-64 string into a `NSData` and just `NSLog` it or examining it in the debugger), and draw some conclusions. For example:

- Image files generally start with special byte sequences (e.g. JPEG start with the hex bytes `FF D8`; PNG generally start with hex bytes `89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A` (e.g. `89 "PNG" CR LF EOF LF`, etc.). Note, there are a dizzying number of different image formats, so this is a non-trivial exercise, but sometimes you can get lucky and it will be self-evident that it's one of these common format when you glance at the first few bytes.
- `NSKeyedArchiver` archives generally start with the string "`bplist`".
- ASCII text consists of codes between `20` and `7F` (with linefeeds represented by `0A`; carriage return and linefeeds represented by `OD 0A`; tab characters as `09`; etc.). Then, again, if it was a text, it's unlikely they'd be base-64 encoding it.
- If it was UTF-8 it would conform to the coding pattern outlined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description). For example, you can look at the first few high bits of the first byte that might conceivably represent a UTF-8 character, and conclude (a) how many bytes the character is represented by and (b) what high bits will be turned on those subsequent bytes. You can often quickly look at it and confirm whether the data conforms to this UTF-8 pattern or not (especially easy to do for most western languages)
- If the first three characters were `EF BB BF`, that often indicates a UTF-8 [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

This is, by no means, an exhaustive list of codes, but just a few that leapt out at me.

To do this programmatically and do so exhaustively would be a non-trivial exercise. But if you're just "eye-balling" a base-64 string and trying to draw some logical inferences, decode it and look at the hex bytes and you can quickly narrow down the possibilities, at the very least. If you're unsure about how to interpret it, update your question with the hex representation of the decoded base-64 string (just the first 16-32 bytes, please), and we might be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Great answer! So now the question is, is there a list about the byte order mark? I only was able to find it about the encoding.

Comment: @DavidG. If you're asking whether there is a table mapping the first few bytes of a file to a file type, there are a few apps that attempt to do so (e.g. google "identify file type without extension"). Maybe one of those provide source code of a list of file signatures.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped me solving multiple issues:)

Comment: Also since we're looking at the beginning of base64 string we don't have to decode it. For example `bplist` will always start with `YnBsaXN0` in base64 and PNG will always start with `iVBORw0KGg`. You should account for "partial" bytes at the end of a mark though.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to clearly distinguish text string and Base64 image encoding string. The only way - check if your string is valid Base 64 encoding string. If it is - probably it is an image. If not - you can be sure it is a text.

How to check if string is valid Base 64 you can ere [How to check whether the string is base64 encoded or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571501/how-to-check-whether-the-string-is-base64-encoded-or-not).