# how to check if a string is a plaintext or base64 format in android

Tags: android, character-encoding, base64

I want to check if a string is in Base64 encoded format or not in an android app. If it is in Base64 then i need to decode it and display the content after decoding. I have used the answer of [Base 64 encode and decode example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360403/base-64-encode-and-decode-example-code) and [How to check whether the string is base64 encoded or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571501/how-to-check-whether-the-string-is-base64-encoded-or-not) but the problem is how to  compare/validate a Base64-regex with the string i got after reading a nfc tag. Thanks!

Comment: This might be hepful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571501/how-to-check-whether-the-string-is-base64-encoded-or-not

Comment: Yes i have seen the question but how to do exactly the same in android because we can not do like var isBase64Valid = base64Rejex.test(base64Data); in android.

Answer (score 0):

It might be late to answer this question but if you are till looking for this, then this might be helpfull.

```
if (org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.isArrayByteBase64(base64String.getBytes())) {
                try{
                    chatTitle = new String(Base64.decode(base64String, Base64.DEFAULT), "UTF-8");
                } catch (Exception e) {}catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

The `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` comes default with Android

Answer (score 0):

try

```
private boolean IsBase64Encoded(String value)
    {
        try {
            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(value, Base64.DEFAULT);
            BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```