# Distinguish byte[] and string from JSON .NET

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, arrays

I'm doing a class that gets a string of a JSON (that represents an object) and I'm deserializing it using JSON.NET from Newtonsoft. As I don't know exactly the object that I need to serialize what I'm doing with the JSON.NET library is to get a Dictionary.

The thing is that I'm processing each property differently depending of its type. I can recognize without problems the date or intes by comparing the parsed object JToken.Type with for instance JTokenType.Date.

However the type JTokenType.Bytes, seem to not be working. Then I have this problem, I have a string that represents a normal string an a string that represents a byte[]. How can I distinguish them? Either by using the JTokenType class or other types? Any idea?

Lot of thanks

Best regards

I attach here an example of the JSON that I'm parsing:

```
{"firstName":"Mario","lastName":"Bross","users":[{"name":"Tony","country":"UK","telephone":"663242342"},{"name":"Ahmed","country":"UAE","telephone":"66934534"},{"name":"Alejandro","country":"ES","telephone":"666243098"}],"firstTable":true,"secondTable":false,"greeting":false,"headerInfo":"This is a test document","footerInfo":"This page ends here","date":"2016-03-29T00:00:00+02:00","remark":"Here we have some remarks","logo":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQAAAAEACAYAAABccqhmAABCP0lEQVR42u1dB3wU1fa+YIBAQu+9KkV6KGlAEkIntJAEFRURO6IgKioIKBYQRRAEqQIBYvfJ38JTsT0rz/aw8BSFJyJIUUQQC7j/+82cm9xMZnZnd2f7Pb/f+UXD7mZ3dr5zT/nOOYwpUaJEiRIlSpQoUaJEiRIlSpQoUaJEiRIlSpQoUaJEiRIlSpQoUaJEiRIlSpQoUaJEiRIlSpQoUaJEiRIlSpQoUaJEiRIlSpQoUaJEiRIlSpQoUaJEiRIlSpQoUaJEiRIlSpQoUaJEiRIlSpQoUaJEiRIlSpQoUaJEiRIlSpQoUaJEiRIlSpQosZZyPqgSJUqiBNzlfVBlJJQoiQCwy6A9y6BxpBVIK9pQ8VjxXPn17BgJJUqUBAjwRqDHGYAdT1qZaxWWNrkRy76zPes/pwPLnHWuphm3dmR9b+5UrC171+ePrc61GteqpIlcE7TX0F+rMr1uJYOhiDMxDsogKFHiIOAFwEqA3vu6+mzEQ2ls9JqL2Nj1s1jBxtUsf/OLrGDLB6yg6H9s3GMnuLq80oKio/z537G8wrdZ3sbn2Jh1K9joR25jQxdfyA1HGmue1JD/7ZpkLGQjIYyDbBhko6AMghIlPgN+5JIOLHfteRzgi7j+k40rOug1uJ3S/M27Wd6Gl9jolfeywfeNZx1Ht+fvsQ7XWlxrkGEQRqGSDYOgREnMA7+85M5XZKNXpPBTeAYr2PwcB92xkIHdtueweS83UI+zoQ9MZUmX9OafoT4ZhZoUVsgGQQ4blDFQEvOgr8AG3dWQu/GTuPv9eEQA3qNB2LSXjV5VyLLmXsjqtWnNP2MDMgjCQ6iijIGSWAR+yUmf81BLlr9xOgf92xw0f0U86K3zCifZmDUvsoELprKG3REuII9Ql7wDK2OgDIGSKDzt02fUZGM3TmL5W16NWsB7MgajV/+DZd1+CatUD55BIzIGwjOQwwSjV6BEScQBXz/tx6xK5nHyWp8y89Gq+ZsOsuFLHmLn5KTza9ScPIPaTK8wIGcQb2EIlDHw7Z5UElTgt5gQz/ILL+an3ofhBLzECU+5xi1+1xV3wePh8p5Oc6/gnyzt+gv4dYNX0IRrPQoREskrqKjCA7/uR1WGDRrwcxbW4afbzSEt1bnR8Uvfc0F63Ppy+HkFYx/9nPW99TpWsVYH8gqQPKwlhQdmhkCJyT25v2ffpqwsM1SFVAECPwF/yx3hnsXHyZ8865XwDg/yNu5j/e+4nVWs2Ylf25ZSeFCNkobCEKgb2uSe/DwlpdbPqf2fZGWp38aQSonfWf2MqxMjAfgRqTAE/W65iV/nc7m2oqRhbYNHoE620vdl+SMpmZsO9s6YQdcokZVmbArjqQyAf8DnMX7BxivC1dWPKh27/ivW68or+HXvSIagIYUGiYZkYSwbAe2+/DEl86KfU7P+erxt57ZUXalNKkhZsuFU4pO7n7thEAf+ZwqcQdaRy19jbQaM4N8BcgQtKEdQk063SjEcFmjg/7pn2rkc/L/+mJLxEtOJVw0pqdpECqOqktFUBsDrU3/o0uZs3JbHFBhDyiX4gw26dyWrWi+VfyftuDZjOpegupQfiKWwQPuMr3XtWuOn1Kxd3AC43u2ajIpKU6qqnMP1bCmpWp28gDgFbW9O/bxN16k4v7TGX/hk6P5+7vrvWI9LJ/PvpivXNlwbG8KCWKgWaJ9tSZs2lY6mZj0P8PP4fw8ZRYQAnen6dCQj0Jg8JmUAbJ/6uSvP5afO2wrwZTXjjtdcTa7eGtr3MXTRM6x68yy6yVExqE+xr5k3EJWH0+GUzAcAfuhH3VLuoBApiWsK12Su3clbaqIMgPenvmLvWej16z92TV73YThUCw6ypAnX0U3flm50Od6NxtyAnvRLzpwmwH80JfOXNlWqdOO/78W1H9cs+tmTDEBjMo4qB+DuorLhyxuzcUXbIh2gqPfXuPSZgLj+E5a/7xIybsm7YfB5i06zQfOLWFxiX/4ddpK8AWNuIBqMgHafHkzOKBDgh37QLflh/nu0Y/fnOpTrEDICPSkX0ICMoqoCWLv8yPA/FvGlvcH3vKGB89E39jj6ug2u/Id28r+882CxAdj60Q+aJ1DnsmdD/9lHr97FWqSfx7/LHpI3IHIDxkpBpIP/LwF+Hvsf7129+gD+bwO5juI6husIMgDdqXxalyomFegaKCnl8uuEnqhozQVQX/rkgGvUwn95fOzYRW+7fj31l/bTm56C1z4/5FrHDUwY9RWIRqNfWI9Jt/HvNJVyAygZ1qM6eLwEgEjzBjTw70nOyDiWmnVKPv3f7NJzLf+3wVzHcj2f6zgyAP0oGdiU4v94yRNS4Nc0+97qrKDo+ViN5QF8CNx6b56HpqKuM7aF6ecqOsOy79zMv99Mrt2oUtBQShBGGnmoGPw/p2SdkMF/KCXzWMfExHwC/QSul5ARGE5GsK3B/VdU4GKXf8Satuy8ol0qqee9tpv2YmhLgXZ0+JJ3WNVGIyk2lkOChAjKC2j36g+9M3ON4Iduad95Jf931P4v53o110lkDAaS+9+CPrPI/ivwa+DP29CP3yRHFJijXEev/obV6zief+dpTO8rQJ28jiEvEI5GoJxVzC90X+9+BxLOOgun/jVcp3K9jgxALte+9HkbUfhTUbn/Avz5G/OjehSXUkM/wYajrFW/qykm7kJVgnrkFodjcrAY/D+mZFxhBn7ozU1bLSLQ38x1Bv33xVyHUfa/FRm7KmFs6IJ98m+epkARk1OITrKOubdJmfHWVCqsZsIXCBeSz+1mwKey3yf8MdO4zuQ6m+stFAIUcM2gBGhj+nyVYv3018FfsHlBJN68YNxNL/zEp4w74vSwHAASmr0Gv7Ou599F8TFKhWdTclBw5CuE2AiU0HuTM1dagf9QSubvKVWr380fO4crPg8YgDdyvZSSf73U6V/G7d+yOFJv3MnrPtIy9W2uf97r58JwQEJO2w2nCkGPSYuIKCOSg40MFYJQGAENoC8nJVX/KTVrmxX4ocvbdHiBP3Ye1wVc55MHcK10+suxf0yf/hEPfjHJB7X9Ftf+n+vw8T80oo83nABvavwxYwSSLllMsTI48+1ZSbNMKIyAdp9+1j2lDQf/Z+7A/5+k1H3x5cvfyx+/iPQeygFMZDoDsAflOIyZ/3IK/BGuoPYWvrXX1fXmbZoRQClOgdkPI9D94oeIMJNKRqBJkI1AcbLv+5TM/hzgB92B/3BK5l+Da9V9lD8e73sZGYC5XNEZmce1D9N5/zFf9yfwb3ogWm/gU3+edq3e/q0Csr9GoEPuffxeGUllwmAageJkn7tMv6yLWrd9kz8enP9HyADA/b+JMv+DmN7+20xi/cXFLvijPNuPcMCJZh+8ztcHf3Wlz341dhOD5wy/22AEROdc5QBVBzTwb+jcOeFISuYGT8CHvte19/5K5cuv4s9bwxU/H+R6O9crmc7/T6akppHzXy72wF+w6aJwdeH94fcjoec0+070DSCsiOEBpCdY0+TbyAiIcKARVQfiHY6j5Xj/Qzvg/yG53x9tExKK+PPWc11HXsA9RP5B81OmVParHquJPx38Ywv7h5rkg864SY/scD2743vXl/uPu4yC5pud3x1zPfnePteMzZ9qwzU8AVtw9lVJL1BThtYdZbXaTKWcQApVBxpKmXR/jUCxy6/RelOzjtkBP3RSg8av8edt4lrIdTXX+6nuP5GqGUkS5Tcmy376h8UEnxCO7sJpihZcxOfeCozCM9xgwHBYeQqqlBdgHbF8D4uvejlVB3qTS11fYgz62jtQXN8/kpq5xC7woevadtzFn4vTfwtXJACXUP3/Kq6jyWM5h95nYiwm/vQvpP/S2qFs7MFgjJ9P/lkK1Dv3HXM9+MJX2kYenPKo4yPmRryNVl301iORB29AFhiQone+86rcp9QhHXzvDkqqDaGSWmuiDQtweeNaF2f5d/VIa2vX5ZfYfkcqliuHJR+P0+m/givyFdczveHH6PrHx6br3+baSqGc4gMgy7KRSnXehg0wFAA+vAEhCCGuXP3v8O+8iyZNvf5Zfl+NZyUddS2JVedNcq3Y5T+QnHGxWSefO93Tq++pNvFVQPh5ik5/uP4LqeY/gbL+3U1c/5g7/cuzcZvvDtXNIo/HOvDzKe2kd2KJJ1733a+PlHrtGZv/E5AxX0rLjB8/w9qNWEoJNvQOdKHyWi0b5cHiU/+1pKQ6R1Myn/IG+DTf7+8Rder+i7/GM1yfINf/QeL9X055CoQobQzeSQyCP2/jsND1xL9QfFrjpEYOwOm/AU8CeYW/zvyt/Z3Dx3/XPA7lEQR8I9FxVrvVLUSw6Uf02iasZLCmWaKt+NT/vlfmMO7yf+8t+KHTmrRAo89zdPoXUs3/DiL8YOpPOlUqGsYq3Ve/0GOwrCN0Pf1iNh5A6QtP39t6/dJtXxcbgn1Hf9NChlB99nlPf6HlKqK6fDhsydesfKVrKNmWZlIZMK4sLw8u/5HUzId9AT507Tnn7uWvs5VO/81E+rlbKvnBI8HgUzHmKybpvnrcX1D0Rijn4gsJJtcehgY5BiEIE0JRGpz39Oea99Pxxpei2xNIn4ZVWxiyMdzC7Ra7B876vmdmf37q7/UV/C92SvqxYrlyiPv/wfUxivvBVESn30WGuL92iJuXQk3zLbwplDfGE+/t0wCI4Zih+PsAvcgRwCtY8fJulR8IVD6gRfqDEt22mwRAbS/hC9261T3sx6kP/bB7yvHqcXH/JNf/CSL8PMD1Vqa3+aI02cvCAMUY+Ec9msS/nFOhZPSJWn+oS3WTVu7QQhARFgxf8JYCreNjxVYdZpWq3iix7oQLXvvzpPQ8X2N9of/tmf5bs0rx28n1f5KSfuhWnMX1CqL6ygM+Y7bNV5T8/h3KGwI1fwG4cLhBUUKUwwL8t/IGHNa+tyArj4k7mLeXPql+46x9vfv+nz/Ah37bq88fXROrvsVf83muT3PdSN1+IPtcw0rm+3Vgpbf7xCTbL+SuPxTuNgRJOSdfN/uu1/2as4/TH0ZJGKfsea8r4DoaCvR7uEr58lc81q7LisMpmb/6C/4DyRmns2vWeo/f1y9Q0m8jZfzv5DqFa77B46gZy/X+cmzEsjahdP2Ffrz3Zw1kdhZvIHuPcMHOCi2U9/ydtQ9vQOQnIAu37gq/5R0RqimD5xz6skf6Pn+BL8A/qEadDwj8zxLXfznTR3xdT+FGf+IgNI/lpJ8wAGdxKxwWO/tE/A9w25nJB4/BU7Z8zpOfaVRiGBcn3Hf0FAiOwo5vfrL1XpWaa+389a4lA69xOQF8WuX19/h6DVHrf5Ey/qLchw6/aRYsxJhM+kmu/8bccBnQKfj6Tr3ezMd2lmogemvXYS25V2Pi0369NowO+hEgMC6qt8DLUWzjilxXDZvp2ps+xFHwT6jf+FN+T79EGX80+mC5x3yp3DfY0IdQlcXwbL9ybOD0BDauaHc43BQov0H2HDrpOKUYcTvA7yTLD7RiERKgXAhPQ4Hbs/YftdD1Qb8xjgHfAvxyrR8cf6z1GkrlPqc6EaPA9Q+DxJ+RAASg+vJ81O6ttvZiNkCg5vxhmIhgEaLtGIZBAb2sdhrzsOvZrIscBb4H8KPBZwbV+nOYPtnnHEO5Ly5WwV+O5SysE8oefysD8PoXh3wGotUizkC76Hh9kRdArkHNFyjRZmNXux4ecJXrcFp2sMC/hsB/CzENxXDSdqxkV0E8i/GpvmeF22BPfw1AOCz1xAxA0WEY6xOG6uetc90z6DrXwbQBjgPfA/jvl8AvjyIL9DzCCDr9hyxpEg5lv2gyAGJyEUIYMYkoFtmD1fM3umYMucnRBJ9ZqW9Yrbr/tgA/KL6XMfOJxOGwpSgcyn6bl4TbjSMMgNNJwGCrMTmIsqECvrPgH6DX+c1i/lsM4O/Agr+TQJ3+vpbW9BbgPyK/zHXB466Htn1dXH5EfkIB338Fvbdn1ervSHX+IgP4Jynwe4z9Qzflxw4PABItQzlQGhSy6IWvoi7Gv23I9KAAn1Z3neyaWPVtAj8Yfluozn8fZfsV+D2e/hlzaoRT5t+oQqKpF16eaxgNRiDQyT0zfb978vFmleLfkMAvGH7zqc5/KQvtKrKIqfvfEM43l8ii2+kFiCRFv4LgCqza/m1E9hC0GrvKtWTg1UEFPnRb514/VY+L224C/nuJ4XcJ1fkV+D0YgLhwYf1ZKTbpQEDcibZYGdONhBFAkjBSjAAIPGuyLw9IHd+TLhtwlSsudcr3/N7dRj39SPhhfdcCAv8Epg/0SKY6f2MFfivO/9j1w8P9ZsOsfwg2+0RjwsxoBML5vaaPXuR6sv/FQQe90OlDbxbrxU6zCgmY6IOefqzwWsRKpvkIhh8GejSS6vwK/GXd/y1PhztAUDLTS4EnojZrLhuBcMsJoElnzIi7XW9m5AUM2AghPuw72u2/4z2Uem8dc//D9CUeSPrNY/oUX22ACCvZN6jAb3n6D7y/aaj3+tka1T1jW3HCLBCjwJURMNeEgkKtO+/TviMDeqq/mHm+236A//YZ7uox5iGTKcIP/kyxP3YKYIb/ROrswxxB9PTXUm6/e9rvzZFSPxftu3YGfUSLEcAo8FDx9O8cPDXgpbzd6UNdlw273W1IAa8D78fy/dbvhNFei6nkdyHTx3ifS/x+dPbFZE+/59Ifkn8FRZ9GCjAwDRiCYR/Rzp6TjQDKhcH6u8mjF7vWZ08KSmIPAz+6jVnqtgW4MHui5oW4Xyt23WdkAG4hA5BJ7r9Y3qlOf1P3f8TybpFInkFJMBYotNhPKCSQXk98wWZXfs4812sZBUFJ4r2ceZ4G/IxRD7j1MMAitPUZxqw5yfS5frOo9DeA6Qs8hQegDIA577/wnkgChLwYJNBbgcKNLARvwOmBo43y1rpmD56mxdfBAD7+zvk5d2p/+7Lht1t6Gd+nD3INGznfu8/TLAU8AAz2vJLpC0Uw2qsptfhWVAagrPtfgbv//40kMIAGLHrrg+kWh1rv27qruIvQCSYkTt5gufkie4/THJ4GqgkgDVmu5+bhQPvcFT5sE7phJ3EAMNwTu/xSmD7eqzZVAFQOoJT7P3pZ+0gEw9aPfvBrOlCkKliCYp6AL1UQNOZMHnqr4yO33CkMDOJ8UIQFVRjuv9Xji/pf4jnet14k8iu/r5dIeYAs4v03kPIA5ZQREO5/XuGMSASC4APAJcY47pgZlnnB48XGD5OF7I4XQ+kMU3eCTdOFhwGKsHgfiPk/75NjaSiKyT3+aP2O4ANgo+/lxALsRvRfFQaUdf83b49EIAD0QpAkiyUvAKAXuwlhDKwowzjtUVp7p9/YoLP0CvtP1CjC8vs5P+cOSwOEMiBCEkeuUY9JH6gwwI77nzK1Fr9gv0cqEMRknVgLA8RkIbAhzTgCoOiCmx/s094K+Ij3Hxg42S35B4lIx67PkIUHTMIAUQ5MUGGAcP9zV+dEMghEGGB3UUi0KWYMimToNYte09znQDP1vAG+qDC4i/dBMoKBcPTa5G8+zc6KR0PQXAoDMO67K4UB1VQYIMg/+Rvvi2QAIAwQJJlYnLmPbPqCG1e7XKdPu/4+dsz1S+75QQU9YnbkFc7JfcSyWciqtIi6v9clPm+0eRpYgZgFgD1/Y6ghqBV1AsbHchhQjqxfBTZuy/uRDgLM2Y/25iCzhB5cakGeOTlvvnYNTn+123Ws/7CAAx9/FwM/RFbflLcw9BbL8iJcfreUXie015VY//Ug04eBnM+1H3UE1mMlSz5j2AD0vqBaJMf/8lZeIdG8fguAgYtv1SX3+2NPatfgj5deDhjwEV6gIQjJRXdlRtB2rV4DhCPHXX4zHTQfeYCHud5OjUHY99dJsQJF/D9iRd9oKYuJtdxPRNmMAIDpwuFztRPTI0D7DHD9teND7Tr89uAyj48/NnCE69crp9gC/rNZF2ruuifgIgdglYNAKOBYlt+O5hX+xfRhoNj4ezXT5wIkcW0W6+VAEf9PjxagiN4A5AMivUUYcT3AhqSanSw+XP7j4y91/Tp5muvEbXNcf//2m5YTODH1ZtexjMGmzzkx/VbXmUOHXKfWrLd8XdBwEWa0z11u631fMny25ftFhx+2/Ab9etbrAFrwfYZyYCtqDY7JPEBJ/J9fuNHbC5p91+sa2HxVO5l6bMvx5jXxeIDel7ZZVBH8+TxQJ3j5OFlxOoIa67Htlp/0v06Z7vrjmedcp7/Z4/IkZ/btd/358nbXyXsWaknC358s4U+YGQBwBgBmT0w8ce1mb9jh2jT0SnPjxA3QrqUbAnrt3Grb4W8a8gB9mb77r26s5gGEAajICrZ43f4LAoqovfsiSNjZcenF0gxPIs/NK3rnu2KKrN2R4Sij4fH+yM7vjvnVcotkmhUzzgh8gPjMgQMup0QYAHHag6XnTQny+3c/taw8wCtBUjJQ186Wpkz5wtAdmM30+QBGWnCMxf/YeupjAtBfI2AnUWfHCBiHZna9uWRSkDebdpwwAsmzXvFqgCZm5bsbeVUGTBdf7hFMvsiube9q7DxfePeTh91qmeX/7f4lLtcffzh+7bzWAXftZ/qIMNCCr5D4AI1ZyYCQmMoD6AZg+JIu/lJRfTUCX+4/bmvarTsjYDUxVwwK8fZk8dcIPPr6Ho/jsr0FvVCtxGcTTF6/7zf2+DTz32pqzy85Y11/vfeBo9fOLx218gS/39cyfTz4tUxfCtKD6SPCajB9/XfMGYA4NnrVGCf46L7KjM3/sZ3hNwOmlQGR5wR4uzdAXs7htSv952lXjUufKQN6lO38GZ6JbL438vevv/IQ4aDrzKHDATEAg0bep3H2TROLSEAeO+bItXNUK8QXMn0h6DSuebGeCNQbgPLW3+jklh5vBfRVrPmy8zewCNQo7h6/45uftMfAG/ClvdhXQUOSE6AvBtSNt9oG/anlq1zHz5tQ6vn7B4xyrbnpYdeql7+2fC7yJrYZh4OmWFYL9hc959e1m7z2w8AZgDptsRx0sUkisE6sNQaVJADHFi4NpQGAbLF583lrAGRiEDwCbweM+Condu12jHBzbOhoDdh2Mvxwu2UwPjLgCq2MCNCKz/ciLVMxfkY7a9aRs7CaHbA1a7zrnPPX+X3tApoMbJ31OiUCb+N6sTQfQDQGxcWeAcjf9EyoDQAEZUWnDYCcC7DrBSAx6YQcn3ilIwZAsPo8ycnb77QEvbFz8PDx3zUdu+gd1859xzwaAJQmrei8qPcjCShKw04IyrkBMQCd8nbwe34F1zlMXw4qMwJjakCIMACVWMGWD8LBANhJCPpiAORcgJ0ba+m2rx25iVGb9/v07z/MdtLvxrlPW4LebLqwnECd9/TnlgYAoYxVBx9+f7bU/OPUtQvYhOeel2NSMDoDsSzkyliuBIgSYDwrKPpfOBgAOwlBXwyA7Pba8QLEwlF/BSw8f5txTsyYZfvv4TN6syZ93es6cQjGQFQ/jI/BABF4FWadf5jnZ6QDO3XtEEbYnW7klfa7ZQ9VAu7heg3TNwTHJCVYGIDKTjUBOfXFu0sI+moAMDRTsAPd5QIwVbiMa/31Ho0q64v8tmCRXwbg1Mq1Xv09VElQwbCTScdj0DeB5xgfj2YjxPRWCznMev3Nrh3GlIneDF8SqY4bgP5zwQV4lOkTgq6j1uBeXFvEWilQNwB10qo6dXGdEncJQV8NAHT19m+0x2N8ljflv1OPbtTUFzn95X/9Gpe95/nXfTakcMc9TQsWSdJ1Uv3d21O/mAy07sMy7wOhhejN8FZQwXHcAAxecJjf9xtUKVBwALLvbB9uBgCSPvtVxw0Akl8/n/yzlNtrpOEe/PDzsmC6copGcQ10MhAAQ6cfSoeChiu2H/sjCHuwQMQqPBAEq4tuf87rU98szDJ+j02ufq7Y+wp5MnDEw5gSDC4ANgZjXfg4rmlc27AYmhFYMgS0/5wOgTQAYk6d16WgfcdME4L+GAAocgzaFqH9x1zZuYu0hhtBZjFLuIHMIkDgLavNTjIQ7bLg3Y8ccY9pX/30wk8cM6rI+i/cuqtMrN/kimddp06ccp3Z+53WY+DNqS+XTsWORvnvie/QzDiEJBk4aiW2BW1mJTsDY5ILUNIFOOz+1EAaADDwfBWzJR/+GADcxIPzHnT9Mu8+rbZuh2wjD9QAu83nZCC14qK7b1P2RK3DTh6PbaeC4aQAkPhucKojk49chRbuPLzKq1PfjG8hpPCtvWWqDiFPBo5a+Ru/77dwfYjrrVzHs5LpQHVjzQBUZDkPDQmkAfDH+sNdN/bze2sARD89ZtVZ0VaF4qQukwCce3epDry/jx716bM8/oA+usvb6TdW9Gf/a5R/uE49srbkxOc/ka+AsTo6apytU19WnNRGGb/0PUc+h6PJwIItf/P7vojpa8NBBrqI6UtD27EYGg9WYgCGLx0aaAPQbtoLPseAG6VTxK4BEKAHIcYsmWWlZ34oa6iMnsLvm33LdbhLPAayL8FM/vrokzJUYeivl03W/v2Zt7/1+j2ahXrGBS33/uPLoF87U9UNANiAMyU2YPsYNQCLA24A/PnyjQlBKwPgK+iLW2w5IMoA5dOdth5nV3zd34fTU/Q0+MVLOHZM6ya0Gtax9+ENrmfe+84r2rTgDxjFbDeDWZkw0NfOjQF4mAzABIMBSIgtAzBsybBgGADEcb66gHJC0MwA+Ar6UvV2HvuWKf+tXGsOlo8/9+lzoCznz+IPMCV99viff8k076Gd/NdMdZ35fn/xtUYyD/V7O23aVonKmY/tdEvLDua1MzEAj5EBmGUwAPWVAQiQAYAiJvQ3IWhmAJzg28MttirfvZmRr5UI4WEgU4+Smq85DW+YemZGwNu5C8jsA+BWg0DlkWBySy5kwvL3bb2vl3cetF2+C9W1UwbAqg9g2KKgGQB5fZcvN8DC82a7fjt42HEDoJX/TpcuYR04dkrrdzcrzeFGRInLF7ELKnfhAE5cwWdwm+Rbs97jIFBPrEJPoINnZyz/4dq5KxeG6trp04E3niYDsFwZABiA/rN6BtMAYFSXrwnBP557Xhtw4aQBQJ3729sXlHlNT8MxfCXoOJXQgjfw4Av/LQM+LXex40PXL/kXWrYWYyioJxFJPStX3l15L6yvnV4GVAag2AD0vblTMA2AVcnIm/KVPwYAratgu6HMhcm7mH8nKMLGmw03spWaub2hSGiBww+Qgm+PEiVagi3Hic292/aUHnx+NPbA03DXVxBx104ZAEMOoPeUs4NtAHBD+eoGmoYHNgGP3XRm7bK+Nqv4KmDjOboMZVyR67KRc11Hss2nCYPG/Ofb3sXe8NLEslV3o9WDfe38TgYOX/KLygHIBgAtkEE2AFCQOwJhAOwA3hiSBFtg/JxKaAkmn9XocEzk1ZaD+CAo28ELQJhhtmAFp3Gwxe9k4KD5R5QBKG0AqrGCol+CZQBwWoH3/uyACRrzzAnxBvBGhfscCkE23J9rjdAFlQmrUdxY6AHmIQycWJjqrWBxCxJvEOQbyvZVfBqSayczDL2fBzBzv+IBlDEAm/cE2gCgvxyLIOX10IJ55q/485792Wngj9gdT4YRW8Z6PMqRVstD4AGZ0Xgx+svb5CsMgKDwmuUCwv3amWratL2KCVjaAFRleYVvB8oA9B+10FXU/xLLkwrNNqEyALihfa1IOCFmE3jMQiUkzVBua5S3VtsRaJXvQCuxPJ7LqIjlvWnCMVKR0dcfSdfOVLtf8qXqBZC7ATEIcezGJwJlADxl5THF1s7E20AYADNSCrLUYlIOBDGwp+k6vp6EdpKBE5Z/oHEUdq/cbLknEL/HEA87uw/tirxZGZ8fHoCcu7C6dt5+B74yA31OpLYf8bHqBpQHgiDmyV27OFQGQFt48dCKkBgA3LBGEYNCsKhSiKcdhiJODkQyMO+Gx7RQyerawSOAZ2CHQITynF0x9gIAcBDRmWd27XzJawTy2plqk15v83t+Eyu9G6APi8HdACUGIOfh6/3NRIOP740BQC4ALbpjRtztqn1eoV88d1/fNxhrxtKX3HsubnoIEl7u2HC+zsK3Ag2SmYjlrUIneE5vrnxa26XnCQig5XrTTLTOZD0X8gG4Pvie7Fw72+vP/djB4FMiNbHhP1npiUAFrPREoJgaCaYPBR08f4QvAELWXeyFww1pJvJUXAyYwE48ZKfNkl2+ii83ntnsf2NyCacmmmLEDe5uffX/+bhJCKeyMcmH62O1fEMj9NyzsFTYhPeG9/kkd9vBshPrtlEzFzP/7Qpex+p6bv1Q/4xmnZ3+JOacvHZuNX/TGX6/P8v0mYALmT4TcCzXZK4tudaMTQPQfZJXcwEHjVxQanYcwI+mEzM59d6/XVeNmG3LTbW7BtwoiMG9MQJoLzY7dXBKGk9T1MLFY+F2mk0s9rdfX8zmR2nvzsFTrU/9/AtNm5acElxHs3q/u6k/7q5dMGYdWC2GNdWchzAP8Bmu67jO5zqF62iuPVkMLggt2QuAaag2uAAoPxn33LkDv5BFJjVkM4WbacZtd9IIIHvsjoVo5v7KcarxRndqWMfWdS9p8wGtCD1au3KAtgLDg0C44wlInog/67zc7OvUtbNtBDJnHeD3+lNc13C9m+vVXHO4dufaVCuJx9hegPJk8WqwvMIP3Ln6r2UUmMahnsAvBBnoQBNzPBkBu2u/0W1ntUQDIqYUOXEDg6UHtp6Vu4/rfvqr3QE79ZHgtMOvt3vtZmz5NCRTjmwZgaQJ/+X3+hNcV3K9g+vlXIdw7cK1EdM3A1WINQOg04Fz16wskzzisajVmGi0mX6z40utP9+Oopxmp3aL0xWnrN3XNSrAaXYjwLV996ujtt+rsZ8dhkWOp5/lwPH1PQo98fFOjadvRejBvj0QemTgAbAIQ8CGwzZfYzLOjiCRh3n9dmvpxmsnvAa7186oGEbq77UzU+Qm3H6WVv13SI1At3O9hOsArudybcBK7wZksWQAqrKhi66Rd8FZEU6QnMKSSDsxfTgq5tThBvTluTgpRT7AU1LQ06BSd7E+jC6Yk/IYNIRGWLxhtc0I5UtUKlZv/1YzDNjzB4WhQskOnhUeY3cNuyfeg69Z/5BqtYYvGzgAF3LNiDUSkLkBSJuWWTt/vbb33XhjYtwWZtebZe8jTcX4Kl+BIBNgkEsA+Lx5vrsMPwg95+fcUZavwMMPcPrD5RoK990vTn6wdfSqU/w+f46VXQqSzvVsFkNLQQT4RRKw4rzWrZvu7J2+cE+fIWXiT8yvR3Y60oEvu/L+bpuRB1ogLLBzEno69ddnT3LVz1sXEdcQm34gRW5WuIWd6glAVADWc72P6/Vcc2OtBFhOBv8L3brV3ZueMe9gn6xjP/bJch1J12NPkHrEaiql5qw6mcIq02a9PfXR1IPuyEi7BqjBgx7sVR0+lNp53BcmFQCxGbgpi4HNwMXAfy0pqc7+Ppl3/EjAh/6Qnnl8UeaETyLlFAq1IjEmD8MwG53l6dRfNuAq05mDkaCiWgMmYkS853od3uL3/uNcH+E6l+skroO5do72CoAAfvkNnTsnfJeeOe1getZBCfiH/tUj+a4WlSv3Zp3Pu1qB24t4nocSgreApBjYhXZOfdT70SUZ6Z/dE0U6bHTs+r/4/b+VEoByF2DUDwIpPvX3pWVcwF393TLw3+2ZfOc5CQldiAiBhojhLH/TSQVu+yqPOodLfO7kZ0wTqULxb9GSU0EJEmvf7IRMSByC6BWS95pxG+L/f3DdSAnA6YYEYFQ2AWmn/u7kPmkc+O8L4B9Izzz6Xs+UO9olJHQi96c3lUJAiMhjQx94TwHbOxXceNB0rer6OPVBqIqmz40kIMqinvIACJesCFbukrWO5Rc6jNrJ7+2nua4lCvC1RAHuxbUFJQArRZMBKLcrLa0RP+U3CeBzI/D7zl5pD+fUqYPTviPXHnTqZ3MdynWU1hnV6/IVCtTeafXzNmujxa3YfNF06pvNdew6Y5utnIk3gEa/hp3XtaUJdV4xMACvoHu+K9cm0UYBLrc/PSuHg/5nAf5vUvs9M6t16zQiPHTjmkrxz2DN7dezoTAAY1itlpPYuKIzCtj2OyKtOPzReOqXGqg6Y5tXNG9vFNOLPO0ksKVD7j9mEv9jDFh/rh2ikQGoxfz/SU1N2ZPeb/H2br1zqczRjkoe4tQfQuAfRtZwENeB2u9HrPhEgdvzUE6c7JZDTu5f4nrita8ip0zmoyIEcGpvH64V2JZy3wXYj96SrUqPAJvwlRT/PxDt8X85adBHPNU2G9Cwg6508venk38I/YQxwEikFIqJklm/2+YrkPtW1z86alypll3wBTyNFItERVIPVGjwAexu7MFzUDWxKh3iOqGSImYwiD0AaEM2rhq3rTWbvSHV/++h+H9UtMb/8qy/yvThGjN93FF3snqZZASyyBvoRd1Q7elx7ViTHhn84p1WYPe+rt/2qqfL7O1Dg4yj661DrMjmi+Eh2PJ0+PgfjhgA+fXR1HWPp+YeTzp0EZaAPE8NQCu4zpHq/10IG1WjKv43MQCNyAPoTIMPUoj+2JN+15YsYSPyFnBRWrMxa/6lQF967Blm7Vux+bBIVO52M5uy68hyyzBRxP0AsugLcNrLwanvdxKw87gvJf4/ZgDOYPoQ0AxD/T+q4n85BKhGXU7N6HQ/lyoAHej/MQWlITVCVKfH19B+N/DOqQr4+iKT6UNvdsvhRxOV3QWYiG8jrovOQ2svxN/+CrOqgV8bgAq2/M0S6m6n8p+YAHSdxP9vpQ3CidL6/1nk1lQhQNejk70ZaRM67WsT6KuQwahE/12L1WnZlhVsPh7L4EdbtNXaLXTuYaCpL1N40UAULSGBqATgxA6r95Y1+0d+H/+f5P7PlQaAiPJfVPL/RRgQJwFanOy1SGtQ7FOZHlOBjEYcE9uCEBKMXFEYq+BHFyTaoM3A/2zWhbbmIeAUs5qiE+4hAQyYnVNd5AOwvyBQ3ZsgEHndvt2i74dS9v9Bpo8Ad+f+Rx0FuDyBugKBvLKk8QT0OMn9kcMHGI26rPslg2IN+HDnC7MnWk7puWrYTK858+7GXt/n8KZgpxTDQyAg5NjZB+FIzd5qMYq2m/Ar+88b+cgpVi7uRZPs/2hivkat+2/aBCSd7nES6MsbgC/PCKhEXkJzlrvu3WgCOE4sjM+WG3eEokFH3l0oK4ahts9d4XNCy90arUXe3NxBnJuAPgezOBzXEJUNAXrj2jD/AP9+qeEnKP/h73i1CqzrRV9J5B8sAcX4r0uJ69IlGtl/dvr/rdSqilBVSwZmzZocTQZAnGwyeQWJPmzaNQM+kn8o/RmXbfryd90ZgbCLoT0MCMVnEdfQSQPgN7EIs//jq71Cwz8e5Xq/RP4RG4Dqkpcble6/J2Ng53Fx5B7V0UqIeYV7oskIwK0VmXgk+oyjzuXynpNUXoDcKhxwik0XTA9BDgGcMgA48f3K/qde+x3V/kXv/51cr2L6+O8eVPmKqQUgvlYRKlGWtAnLvuu2aIz3MX/PKtGH8l4ghnUg+y8z3SLRAzCy95w0AH4pSn81WrzJ9O0/G6Xa/4VEfDuXyt6JLIbGf/vqKVSgLGk9VrFWB+5aHQnWDeXXCWCTx4+xZ2bAh0G4aPjcgGfYEetiJdYrOw9G1nBNk3BA5+x/FPr30+em/fx+fYE6/1ZLyb8xUu1fDP+MU+D37AXEk7vUnA2cvyAY4IeLjLHTgWT0fdR3tOUSDoQEigDlXVgjb1UO7enf/C1i/mH7L0Z/z2T67P+BxHptzGJs+48TlOJEjTRUo1E3ll/4o69ur3FkltVSEIB/+cu7A1bbRynPDPyzB0/zO9EXi4qRYHZnAgTp9EfpTwz+wOTfPKZv/z1bSv7FxVLyzx8jIJKBtTT3KWvOHF9PdiS5QjUSCi4/GnWsEn0Zox5QYPZRMRIMxj3QYZsXp/9mrsuk0p9g/...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"}
```

The last property is a picture (byte[])

Comment: Do you have sample input of the ambiguous case? If you do, it might be best if you could post it in your question.

Comment: I mean, I cannot distinguish any case, so it is not a case of ambiguity. I don't know how to know if a string it is just a string or a bytes[] on string form

Comment: Some real ambiguous JSON data would be best to add to your question...

Comment: Ok, I have added an example on the Question, I want to distinguish for example that "firstName" is a String and logo is a byte[]. Any idea or approach I could take?

Comment: Do you not know the schema ahead of time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a string of printable characters, you want to determine whether that string has been base64 encoded or not. This is not possible. You can determine if a string *may have* been base64 encoded:

[How to check whether the string is base64 encoded or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571501/how-to-check-whether-the-string-is-base64-encoded-or-not)

But it is possible for a user to construct a string that looks as if it was base64 encoded, but in fact was not.

If you have control over the data source, you should add an extra metadata field to indicate whether a field is bas64 encoded or not.