# How to check a "byte[] b" (holding a file content) is encoded in base64 or not..? in java

Tags: java

Here i have a code which accept a file content in byte array, i want to check whether its in base64 format or not,before converting it to base64 and returning.. can anyone help me out here

```
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;
public static String encodeInByteArray(byte[] b)
  {
    BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
    return encoder.encode(b);
  }
```

Below is the code which i tried to check for base64 format:

```
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class Encoder
{
public static String encodeInByteArray(byte[] b)
  {
      String regex =
                "([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*"+
                "([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)";
        Pattern patron = Pattern.compile(regex);
        String s=b.toString(); 
        if (!patron.matcher(s).matches()){

    BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
    return encoder.encode(b);
        }
        else 
            return s;
  }

  public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException
  {
      FileInputStream fs= new FileInputStream("Sample.pdf");
      String s= fs.toString();
      byte[] b = s.getBytes();
      encodeInByteArray(b);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling `b.toString()` doesn't do what you might expect - the resulting string will be something like `[B@106d69c`, because arrays don't override `toString`. (In a similar vein, calling `fs.toString()` won't give you the contents of the file as a string).

To get a `String` from a `byte[]`, use the constructor:

```
new String(b)
```

But you probably want to specify a particular charset, e.g.:

```
new String(b, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)
```

otherwise you may get different results, depending upon your JVM's configuration.

Answer (score 1):

First solution you could parse the file, or parse the file part way (to save resources) and determine if a line is base64 encoded. See this answer for the String base64 encoding check.

[How to check whether the string is base64 encoded or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571501/how-to-check-whether-the-string-is-base64-encoded-or-not)

A second solution would be is that if you have complete control over the file saving and encoding, you could place a byte at the head or tail of the file indicated if its base64 encoded or not, which should be faster then the above solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Base64.isBase64(byte[] arrayOctet)` from apache's [commons-codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/).

Be aware that whitespaces are valid at the moment as stated in the [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#isBase64(byte[])).