# how to identify base64 type in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am providing API in Ruby On Rails for android application. All going well but i am facing problem when i got base64. I didn't able to identify base64 type(image,pdf,song or any other type like doc). Is there any way to identify the exact type of base64.
        Thnaks in Advance.

Comment: try googling for the same, someone wrote for ruby here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13520156/2545197

Comment: but @Abhinay I want to know the type of base64 like the base64 is an image or pdf file or any other type of file......

Comment: It very complex to identify the type of the file from base64, atleast I couldn't find it on the internet. though you can try a small hack and send `filename ` with extension as a `json` attribute along with your `base64 string` and then you dont have to run through all the code just to identify the type.

Comment: I have a similar situation, and I'm afraid you'll have to submit the mime type together with the Base64 payload. We do that in our uploader code, where we extract the mime type before encoding and sending them together to the backend.