# Android: How to check if string is Base64 encoded?

Tags: java, android, base64

I am not sure how to check if a String is Base64 encoded or not using `android.Base64`. I know in standard Java using `java.util.Base64` calling `Base64.getDecoder().decode()` would through an `IllegalArgumentException` if the String wasn't already in Base64, but on android I get no such error, so how can I check if it is Base64 encoded?

Comment: Fair warning: just because a string _can_ be decoded with Base64 does not mean it was actually encoded with Base64 or will produce meaningful output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check whether the string is base64 encoded or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571501/how-to-check-whether-the-string-is-base64-encoded-or-not)

Comment: @LouisWasserman I know that, but I would like to know if the String is able to be decoded. If not I want an error to be thrown or some indication that it couldn't be decoded.

Comment: @Miller This didn't work for me, or maybe I didn't apply it correctly.

Comment: What is your string, that can't be checked using common code?

Comment: Not a specific string, but for example: if I try to decode the String "this-is-a-test" I should get an error because "-" is not part of the Base64 scheme, but I don't get any errors or indication that what was asked to be decoded was not in fact a valid input.

Comment: @Miller Nevermind, I apologize. I was implementing it incorrectly but have now fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Add to Gradle:

```
implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9'
```

Add to your code:

```
if (Base64.isBase64(yourString)) {
   //do stuff
} else {
   //do other stuff
}
```

Comment: I am getting `No static method isBase64(Ljava/lang/String;)Z in class Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64; or its super classes`

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
   try{
     Base64.encode("thestringyouwanttocheck".getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT);
   }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
      Toast toast=Toast.makeText(context,"Illigal Input",duration);
      toast.show();
   }
```