# Base64 checker for Android

Tags: android, base64

Is it possible to check Base64 images before send to web server.Web server accept base64 image so i convert my image by this method:

```
   public void makeJSON_For_Image(int imageSize, String img_Address, String guid) {
        imageSizes = imageSize;
        img_Address = img_Address.substring(7, img_Address.length());
        byte[] bytes = null;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int bytesRead;
        try {
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(img_Address);
            ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            bytes = output.toByteArray();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LoggerExeption.log(e.getMessage() + "\n", e.getStackTrace());
        }
        String pic = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

But some times, service got an error because it can not convert base64 to an image.

Is it possible to check base64 that is correct converted or not?

### Edit

According  `Alexandru Sandu` suggestion I used this regular expression like this:

```
String pic = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
String regex = "^([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)$";
if(pic.matches(regex)){
    System.out.println("it's a Base64");
}
```

but my if condition return **false** !!!
This is a part of my base46:

pic =

```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```

Seems is it not correct!!

But i checkd my pic in [this](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter) online base 64 checker, my image appeared completely...

Comment: What are the requirements for a valid image? If all images have to be .png, then you can verify the file signature (http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Structure.html) which is an inexpensive way of determining if an image is somewhat valid.

Comment: That image comes from mobile cammera and, yes it has png extention.Image is correct but base64 is Doubtful

Comment: You want to make a check in code? or you just want to check it for the sake of development? if it is the latter get the base64 with a breakpoint and check it here: https://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: If it is the first, check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571501/how-to-check-whether-the-string-is-base64-encoded-or-not