# Regex for base64-encoded SHA1 for android signature hash AADB2C android platform

Tags: android, regex, azure-ad-b2c

I need a regex for android signature hash which is used in azure in a field presented on picture.

I used something like that:

`"^(?=.{28}$)(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?$"`

It's matching words base64-encoded with 28 characters words but it will also match e.g. `platformAndroidSignatureHash` which azure decline (presented on a picture).

**WORKING EXAMPLE:**

- 2pmj9i4rSx0yEb/viWBYkE/ZQrk=
- aPz8/NARbPz8pPzg/Iz9aPz8NCg=

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It matches `platformAndroidSignatureHash` because the last part with the equals signs is optional.

You could rewrite the pattern as

```
^(?=.{28}$)(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})+[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2,3}==?$
```

The pattern matches;

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=.{28}$)` Positive lookahead, assert 28 characters
- `(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})+` Repeat 1+ times 4 chars of the listed in the character class
- `[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2,3}` Repeat 2-3 times matching one of the listed chars
- `==?` Match either `=` or `==`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H9dYBu/1)

Answer (score 1):

get familiar with [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding, especially read about **padding**, but in short: your "faked" `String` should probably ends with `=` or `==`. you can't use regexp in here, as you should do some bitwise math, as every base64 digit needs 6 bits, in the meanwhile common usage (e.g. printing on screen) would use 8 bits per digit. you have to calculate/respect this padding. more info in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571501/how-to-check-whether-a-string-is-base64-encoded-or-not) topic (read ALL answers and comments, accepted one isn't reliable!)