# Different base64 encoding validation in java.util and apach-commons

Tags: java, kotlin, base64, apache-commons

Let's consider the following codebase:

```kotlin
val str = "contextId"
println(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.isBase64(str))
String(java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(str))
```

It prints:

```
true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Last unit does not have enough valid bits
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:867)
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:566)
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:589)
     ...
```

It looks contradictory for me.

Could you please explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [`isBase64`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#isBase64-java.lang.String-) states (emphasis mine)

> Tests a given String **to see if it contains only valid characters within the Base64 alphabet**.

It says nothing about the fact that the string can be decoded or has an appropriate length. Hence it returns `true`.

On the other hand `java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(str)` actually tries to decode the string, but fails because the string doesn't have an appropriate length.

Comment: Well, so Is there validation method which answers if it is possible to decode in boolean format without exception handling ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow Not Java/Kotlin specific, but check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/8571501/6395627

Comment: @Slaw
Yes, I've read exactly it. I've taken it from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14217969/2674303

Comment: @gstackoverflow I'd say go with [John Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8571544/133203) instead.

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca I am surprised if there are no library for that